# Пробелы в числовых интервалах

Tags: пунктуация, тире, дефис, перечисление, пробелы

Имеется газета со сдвоенным номером: 3-4.
Насколько я знаю, номера будут писаться через дефис (короткое тире) без пробелов. А если у номеров есть номера в скобках, не надо ли добавить пробелы?
3 (11)-4 (12) или 3 (11) - 4 (12)?

Comment: ну коли вы перед скобкой делаете пробел, то уж вокруг тире они просто необходимы. Иначе вообще не воспринимается зрительно. Но я сольно сомневаюсь, что пробелы перед скобками нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое.
Номера будут писаться не через дефис, а с использованием **короткого тире** (без пробелов):
3–4; 11–12.

1. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов:
   в) к о л и ч е с т в е н н ы х, например: *рукопись объемом восемь — десять авторских листов (то же цифрами: 8–10); 5–6-кратное превосходство.*
   [§82. Соединительное тире](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm) (Розенталь)

Второе.
Обычное оформление номеров газет:
№62 (30994) 24–27 июля 2020 года (["Правда"](https://gazeta-pravda.ru/))
№ 30 (838) 22.07 — 28.07.2020 (МК)
№ 29 (2070) 15–21 июля 2020 г. (АиФ)

Пояснение: "Грамота" рекомендует знак процента и номера отбивать пробелом (см. [Вопрос **№ 265643**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)).

Третье.
Сдвоенный номер я бы оформила так (если нужно обязательно указать сквозные порядковые номера): **№ 3–4 (11–12)**.

Сдвоенный номер газеты ["Собеседник"](https://pressa.ru/files/issue/private/sobesednik/2020/15-16-2020/raw_issue/sobesednik-2020-15-16-2020.pdf) (с одним сквозным номером):
**№15–16 (1799) 29 апреля — 12 мая 2020 г.**

[Отдельные экземпляры журналов (газет)](https://www.libex.ru/qna/tech/mag/)

P. S. Для сведения ([Различие тире и дефиса](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0/)):
дефис **-**
короткое тире (Alt0150) **–**
длинное тире (или просто тире; Alt0151) **—**

Comment: А я думал, что тире бывает трёх видов: короткое, среднее и длинное. И приравнял по длине короткое тире к дефису (наш верстальщик так и делает, и я думал, что он знает, что делает). Спасибо!

Comment: Вдогонку: а можно ли с всё-таки цифрами  вместо короткого тире использовать обычное (длинное)?

Comment: Я думаю, что можно. Посмотрите, у Розенталя: просто "соединительное тире" (без каких-либо короткое или длинное). Уж пусть лучше будет обычное тире, чем дефис. P. S. Кланяюсь Вам за вопрос — заставили поползать везде!

Comment: Хорошо, Вы хоть знаете где "ползать" :), а я уж несколько лет всё никак не освою все тонкости редакторства.

Comment: Извиняюсь, если замучил вопросами: а если номер переходит на другой год: 12–1 (122–123) — будет так? Просто, зрительно смотрится не очень.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что это должно выглядеть так: 12.2019 — 01.2020 (122–123).

Comment: Да там год указывается вместе с месяцем, а номера отдельно

Comment: Уф! Ну тогда так: 12–01 (122–123) 12.2019 — 01.2020.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: И напоследок — еще вариант (мне он кажется наиболее приемлемым, во всяком случае, зрительно): 12–01 (122–123) декабрь 2019 — январь 2020.

Comment: Да, то что надо!